# How to stop scrolling up tableview header with cells in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, scroll, header, tableview

I have a tableview header that is fixed at the top in portrait mode.

But when I change the view to landscape mode it is scrolling up with the cells.

I could not find what is wrong. The header I am using is also a `UITableviewcell` of custom style.

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean tableview header? Is it a section name/header ? Do you have only one section or more?

Comment: i have a header for the tableview and there is only one section.it is fixed in portrait mode but scrolls up in landscape mode.

Comment: You may check this [tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-header-footer-table-view-ios8-swift) in swift that has 3 sections and a header view cell that is used dynamically for all 3. The header is for the section. The default behavior is that the section header scrolls up only when the next section comes to focus. It does not scroll up in landscape mode. You may download code and compare it with yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the tableview style into plain in  landscape. then it stop the scrolling the header of the table